# My migrated zsh terminal looks werid

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I migrated my zsh setup to another machine, but it looks weird, instead of regular "UI" look I see weird symbols

 ✔  13s   name@damain  16:30:23 

what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to migrate the customized font that the old system's terminal app was using. All of the ``'s appear to be U+E0B2, which is a "private use" Unicode character with no standard meaning – but most likely you were using a Powerline-patched font where U+E0B2 is used for the "arrow triangle" character.